# target class doen not exist in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i used laravel 8 for project which get abnormal error than mentioned target class does not exist

the route that defined in web.php is :

```
Route::get('/category/all', [CategoryController::class, 'ALLCat'])->name('all.category');
```

and at the top of the web.php i include the class

```
use app\Http\Controllers\CategoryController;
```

and the full error is :

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [app\Http\Controllers\CategoryController] does not exist.
```

could anyone help me pls ?

Comment: have you tried using `App\Http\...` instead of `app\Http\...`?

Comment: yes it worked ... there wrote actually "app" but when i changed to "App" worked great